# Is there any php function fill an array with string values?

Tags: php, arrays

My code:

```
$a = array_fill(5, 6, 'banana');
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [5]  => banana
    [6]  => banana
    [7]  => banana
    [8]  => banana
    [9]  => banana
    [10] => banana
)
```

But I wanted it something like below

```
Array
(
    [5]  => banana 1
    [6]  => banana 2
    [7]  => banana 3
    [8]  => banana 4
    [9]  => banana 5
    [10] => banana 6
)
```

Is there any other php function there to achieve above? If yes, could you please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you do your own ?, it's quite easy actually

Comment: use foreach loop and its rly easy :D

Comment: I know how to produce above using for/foreach/while loops but I thought there might be something there to increment the number alongwith the string value, so the question.

Comment: @user1421214 no there is not.

Comment: KalpeshMehta's comment should be the correct answer. btw couldn't you search php manual? i think it takes less time to write the code than asking this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test_print_value($item2, $key, $some_value)
{
    echo $some_value." $item2<br />\n";
}

array_walk(range(0,10), 'test_print_value', 'Banana Apple ');
```

Output:

```
Banana Apple 0
Banana Apple 1
Banana Apple 2
Banana Apple 3
Banana Apple 4
Banana Apple 5
Banana Apple 6
Banana Apple 7
Banana Apple 8
Banana Apple 9
Banana Apple 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, but you can write it yourself easily:

```
<?php
function custom_array_fill($start_index, $num, $value) {
    $result = array();
    for($i = 1; $i < $num + 1; $i++) {
        $result[$start_index + $i - 1] = $value . " " . $i;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im That comment was added after I posted my answer. I am not psychic.

Comment: oops. apology. but i think you can edit your answer to reflect the information

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use array_walk function?

```
$a = array_fill(5, 6, 'banana');
array_walk($a, function(&$item, $key) {
    $item = sprintf('%s %d', $item, ($key-4));//subtract 4 from key to get 'banana 1'
});
```

Just do not forget to pass *$item* as a reference (with the *&* character). Otherwise, you will not modify your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFillArray($index,$size,$value){
    $array = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
        $array[$index + $i] = $value." ".$i;        
    }
    return $array;
}
```